# ASP.NET MVC3 - Usage of Html.ActionLink

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3, html.actionlink

I need to use the Html.ActionLink in the format: property of the grid.Column specification. 
My code goes as below:

```
grid.GetHtml(

  grid.Columns( 
    grid.Column(header: "Column 1", format: (item) => @<div class='webgrid-bookname-column-style'> @item.BookName </div>),
    grid.Column(header: "Column 2", format: (item) => Html.ActionLink(item.StartTime, "ShowShippingFileMessage", new { @id = item.BookName }))
  )
)
```

When I use this syntax, it gives me the compilation error of 
The best overloaded method match for `System.Web.Helpers.WebGrid.Column(string, string, System.Func<dynamic,object>, string, bool)` has some invalid arguments
When I change the item.StartTime above with a normal text like "Edit" then it works fine.

I am new to ASP.NET, can anyone please help me understand what is wrong with the above statements?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

<strike>The format parameter is of type `Func<dynamic, HelperResult>`.

It must return a `HelperResult`, not an `IHtmlString`.

It is defined this way to allow you to pass an [inline helper](http://blog.slaks.net/2011/04/dissecting-razor-part-9-inline-helpers.html).

To pass an inline helper, remove `(item) =>`; inline helpers implicitly generate a lambda expression with an `item` parameter.

To pass a normal lambda expression, you need to make it return a [`HelperResult` instance](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.webpages.helperresult%28v=vs.99%29.aspx).

`HelperResult`s [take an `Action<TextWriter>`](http://blog.slaks.net/2011/02/dissecting-razor-part-7-helpers.html#HelperResult), so you would write</strike>

```
item => new HelperResult(w => w.Write(Html.ActionLink(...).ToHtmlString()))
```

**EDIT**: I  hadn't realized that the parameter is declared as `Func<dynamic, object>`.  That means you can either pass an inline helper or any other lambda expression.
Your second example ought to work.

You can also use an inline helper. To do that without an HTML tag, use the special `<text>` tag:

```
item => @<text>@Html.ActionLink(...)</text>
```

Razor will drop the `<text>` from the output.

Comment: Thanks for your quick response. I tried both the options but it did not help. I am still getting the same error.

Comment: It is the same error message. Did not change ----  CS1502: The best overloaded method match for 'System.Web.Helpers.WebGrid.Column(string, string, System.Func<dynamic,object>, string, bool)' has some invalid arguments

Comment: I am not sure if I understand your question. But this is what I get from the web page --------------------------------\Index.cshtml(96,17): error CS1502: The best overloaded method match for 'System.Web.Helpers.WebGrid.Column(string, string, System.Func<dynamic,object>, string, bool)' has some invalid arguments
\Index.cshtml(98,27): error CS1503: Argument 3: cannot convert from 'lambda expression' to 'System.Func<dynamic,object>'

Comment: That usually means you have some syntax error in your lambda.

Comment: Try `new { id = (string)item.BookName }`

Comment: You can't combine a lambda and an inline helper.  Inline helpers implicitly generate `item => `, so you shouldn't.

Comment: I removed the item => lambda expression. Still gives the same error. I am not sure if I am doing it right. --------------------------- grid.Column(
                    header: "Stock Selection / Shipping File + XML",
                    format: @<text> @Html.ActionLink(item.ShippingFileStartTime, "ShowShippingFileMessage", new { id = (string)item.BookName }) </text>
                ),

Answer (score 0):

The display string you are passing is of the type DateTime. Try giving String Input.

```
grid.Column(header: "Column 2", format: (item) => Html.ActionLink(item.StartTime.ToString(), "ShowShippingFileMessage", new { @id = item.BookName }))
```